# Migration failed while trying to create a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I am trying to connect two tables with a code first migration. I thought EF would create many to many relationship table itself but I get error "build failed". While building whole project everything works fine. It's just the migration.

Following are my models -

**Task:**

```cs
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndedAt { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Required]
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string Description { get; set; }
public virtual TaskGroups TaskGroup { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "text")]
public string WantedUser { get; set; }
```

**TaskGroup:**

```
[Required]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string GroupName { get; set; }
public virtual Tasks Tasks { get; set; }
```

At first I've tried with ICollection<> but I got the same error.
My project is .Net Core 3.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

**Tasks**

```
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndedAt { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string WantedUser { get; set; }
        public IList<TaskGroupTask> TaskGroupTask { get; set; }
```

**TaskGroups**

```
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public IList<TaskGroupTask> { get; set; }
```

**TaskGroupTask**

```
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }
        public Tasks Tasks { get; set; }
        public TaskGroups TaskGroups { get; set; }
```

**DbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<TaskGroupTask>(e =>
           {
               e.HasKey(p => new { p.TaskId, p.TaskGroupId });
               e.HasOne(p => p.Tasks).WithMany(t => 
               t.TaskGroupTask).HasForeignKey(p => p.TaskId);
               e.HasOne(p => p.TaskGroups).WithMany(tg => 
               tg.TaskGroupTask).HasForeignKey(p => p.TaskGroupId);
           });
        }

 public DbSet<TaskGroupTask> TaskGroupTask { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want `Task` ang `TaskGroup` to be in a many-to-many relation? And, what is the version of Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Yes exactly. EF Core version 3.1.10

Comment: Why doesn't `TaskGroups` has the property name for `IList<TaskGroupTask>` type? Is that just a typo, or is that in your code too?

Comment: I _copy-pasted_ your edited code and it created 3 expected tables on my database. Of course, I fixed that typo(?) and used `public IList<TaskGroupTask> TaskGroupTask { get; set; }` in `TaskGroups` class.

Comment: Yes I copy-pasted less than I should and forgot to write the rest sorry :/ Well then there is probably something wrong in my whole project :/

Answer (score 0):

Since I have some time, I've decided to pull all  pices of the code in one place. I think it would be very usefull sample  how to create code-first many-to-many relations for database tables. This code was tested in Visual Studio and a  new database was created without any warnings:

```
public class Task

    {
        public Task()
    {
        TaskTaskGroups = new HashSet<TaskTaskGroup>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndedAt { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string WantedUser { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TaskTaskGroup.Task))]
    public virtual ICollection<TaskTaskGroup> TaskTaskGroups { get; set; }
}


public class TaskGroup
{
    public TaskGroup()
    {
        TaskTaskGroups = new HashSet<TaskTaskGroup>();
    }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TaskTaskGroup.TaskGroup))]
    public virtual ICollection<TaskTaskGroup> TaskTaskGroups { get; set; }
}

public class TaskTaskGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TaskId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TaskTaskGroup.Task.TaskTaskGroups))]
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }

    public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TaskGroupId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TaskTaskGroup.Task.TaskTaskGroups))]
    public virtual TaskGroup TaskGroup { get; set; }
}


public class TaskDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TaskDbContext()
        {
        }

        public TaskDbContext(DbContextOptions<TaskDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaskGroup> TaskGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaskTaskGroup> TaskTaskGroups { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=Task;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TaskTaskGroup>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Task)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TaskTaskGroups)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_TaskTaskGroup_Task");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.TaskGroup)
                    .WithMany(p => p.TaskTaskGroups)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TaskGroupId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_TaskTaskGroup_TaskCroup");
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: To be honest it doesn't changed anything. I still have two tables, No extra table for many to many relationship. :(

Comment: Sorry since I noticed that you have  public virtual TaskGroups TaskGroup { get; set; } I thougt  you need one to many. I changed my answer, pls check again.

Comment: I got build failed again :(

Comment: I made some changes , try again

Comment: Now an error says that I need to give this new table a primary key as well

Comment: Yes, I usuall do it too, even if don't need it . Check my answer.

Comment: Ok now I got 
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'TaskGroups.Tasks' of type 'ICollection<Tasks>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227111/discussion-between-sergey-and-san).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a joining entity, like `MyJoiningEntity` or `TaskGroupTask`, whose sole purpose is to create a link between `Task` and `TaskGroup`. Following models should give you the idea -

```cs
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<JoiningEntity> JoiningEntities { get; set; }
}

public class TaskGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public IList<JoiningEntity> JoiningEntities { get; set; }
}

// this is the Joining Entity that you need to create
public class JoiningEntity
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }

    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public TaskGroup TaskGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can configure the relation in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class, like -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<JoiningEntity>(e =>
{
    e.HasKey(p => new { p.TaskId, p.TaskGroupId });
    e.HasOne(p => p.Task).WithMany(t => t.JoiningEntities).HasForeignKey(p => p.TaskId);
    e.HasOne(p => p.TaskGroup).WithMany(tg => tg.JoiningEntities).HasForeignKey(p => p.TaskGroupId);
});
```

This will define a composite primary key on `JoiningEntity` table based on the `TaskId` and `TaskGroupId` properties. Since this table's sole purpose is to link two other tables, it doesn't actually need it's very own `Id` field for primary key.

**Note:** This approach is for EF versions less than 5.0. From EF 5.0 you can [create a many-to-many relationship in a more transparent way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many).

Comment: Now I got this error
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TaskGroupTask_Tasks_TaskId' on table 'TaskGroupTask' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: @San, remove any references of other entity from your entity. Neither of the two entities should know about (have a reference) the other entity.  For example, remove `public virtual Tasks Tasks { get; set; }` from  `TaskGroup`

Comment: I've already got rid of any other references. Those table are now free from references to anything except those changes I made following Your answear :(
no record in database as well...

Comment: @San, Well, with those models and configuration I posted, after applying migration (`add-migration` and `update-database`) I'm having a `Task` table, a `TaskGroup` table and a `JoiningEntity` table in my database.

Comment: I will edit my first post with the actual configuration. Please take a look at those maybe I can't see something important